# js sort by id on button

Tags: javascript, sorting, button

http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/nXkDp/

Hi, im trying to hookup this script onto button, but it's not working. i have no idea why.

```
var sortID = function()
{
var toSort = document.getElementById('list').children;
toSort = Array.prototype.slice.call(toSort, 0);

toSort.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aord = +a.id.split('-')[1];
    var bord = +b.id.split('-')[1];
    // two elements never have the same ID hence this is sufficient:
    return (aord > bord) ? 1 : -1;
});

var parent = document.getElementById('list');
parent.innerHTML = "";

for(var i = 0, l = toSort.length; i < l; i++) {
    parent.appendChild(toSort[i]);}
};
```

Comment: Probably because your HTML is missing a button

Comment: Is the question "How to hook this code to a button?" or "Why doesn't this sort function work on my list?" EDIT: I just looked at the fiddle and apparently the sort does work. Are you telling us you were able to write a sort function like that but you can't do a button click event handler?

Comment: The way the function is coded is quite *advanced difficulty* for someone who has no idea on how to bind event on click. Have you used the [**search**](http://stackoverflow.com/search) button or even tried looking in any [**popular search engine**](http://www.google.com) before asking your question?

Flagged following the **[checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) element #1**: *Have you done some research before asking the question?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a button and onload, assign it's `onclick` handler to your `sortID()` function:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nXkDp/30/)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Sort" />
```

Javascript:

```
var sortID = function () {

    var toSort = document.getElementById('list').children;
    toSort = Array.prototype.slice.call(toSort, 0);

    toSort.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aord = +a.id.split('-')[1];
        var bord = +b.id.split('-')[1];
        // two elements never have the same ID hence this is sufficient:
        return (aord > bord) ? 1 : -1;
    });

    var parent = document.getElementById('list');
    parent.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0, l = toSort.length; i < l; i++) {
        parent.appendChild(toSort[i]);
    }

};

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = sortID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an event handler to a button as follows:

```
document.getElementById('sortButtonIdHere').addEventListener('click', function() {    
    // your code here    
}, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nXkDp/31/

If you're concerned about supporting IE8 and older, you could use:

```
document.getElementById('sortButtonIdHere').onclick = function() {    
    // your code here    
};
```

Or you could add a test for whether `.addEventListener()` is defined and if not use `attachEvent()` as [explained at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

HTML :

```
<div id="list">
    <div id="categorie5.1-4">4</div>
    <div id="categorie5.1-3">3</div>
    <div id="categorie5.1-5">5</div>
    <div id="categorie5.1-1">1</div>
    <div id="categorie5.1-2">2</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="keyMe()" value="hook">
```

Javascript :

```
function keyMe(){
    var toSort = document.getElementById('list').children;
    toSort = Array.prototype.slice.call(toSort, 0);

    toSort.sort(function(a, b) {
        var aord = +a.id.split('-')[1];
        var bord = +b.id.split('-')[1];
        // two elements never have the same ID hence this is sufficient:
        return (aord > bord) ? 1 : -1;
    });

    var parent = document.getElementById('list');
    parent.innerHTML = "";

    for(var i = 0, l = toSort.length; i < l; i++) {
        parent.appendChild(toSort[i]);
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you

here is the link : jsfiddle.net/dp6Vr/